# Shifting an image?

Tags: vb6

I made a program to cut an image into four parts. Each part should be put in a new `picturebox`, but the part that is to be cut from the image should still be in the same location in the original picture.

How can I make the part 2, 3 or 4 of image in location 1 in `picturebox2` (beginning from (0,0), the position in the array still not in the same location in `picture box1`)?

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

   h = Picture1.ScaleHeight
   w = Picture1.ScaleWidth

   For j = 0 To h - 1
      For i = 0 To w - 1
         imag(i, j) = gray(Picture1.Point(i, j))
      Next
   Next
   Picture2.Width = Picture1.Width
   Picture2.Height = Picture1.Height

   For j = h / 2 To h
      For i = 0 To w / 2
          k = imag(i, j)
          Picture2.PSet (i, j), RGB(k, k, k)
      Next
   Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an new vertical index for the second picture that starts at zero.

```
Dim j2 As Integer = 0
For j = h / 2 To h
    For i = 0 To w / 2
        k = imag(i, j)
        Picture2.PSet (i, j2), RGB(k, k, k)
    Next
    j2 += 1
Next
```

Note: In VB6 you would have to write

```
Dim j2 As Long
j2 = 0

...

    Next
    j2 = j2 + 1
Next
```

Comment: thank u very much , but can u explain me in simple way this Adding  please

Comment: Sure. `j` goes from `h/2` to `h` but you want the copied picture to start a `y = 0`. Therefore don't insert it at `y = j`, instead create a new index `j2` that starts at `0`. Since the `For`-statement increments only `j`, you have to increment `j2` explicitly with `j2 += 1` (which is the same as `j2 = j2 + 1`) at the end of the loop. Alternatively, you could insert the pixel with `Picture2.PSet (i, j-h/2), RGB(k, k, k)`.